# Life time of QTcpSocket

Tags: android, qt, sockets

I'm currently developping an Android application which connects to a server through TCP. The server is written in Qt and runs on a computer.

In server side, I use a `QTcpServer` and the signal `QTcpServer::newConnection()` to get the `QTcpSocket` newly connected with `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()`. I have implemented a class I called `SocketManager`, which manages the data received by this socket.

In Android side, I use java Socket to connect to the server.

All work great. When the Android side disconnects from the server, my `SocketManager` object is well notified and destroys itself. But I would like to manage properly the case when for example the Android device goes to offline or is turned off. In that case, I'm not notified of the disconnection of Android. I connect these signals of my `QTcpSocket`:

- `QAbstractSocket::disconnected()`,
- `QAbstractSocket::stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)`
- `QAbstractSocket::error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)`
- `QObject::destroyed(QObject*)`, thinking that perhaps the QTcpSocket is internally destroyed by the QTcpServer.

But no signal is received when the Android device goes offline or is turned off.

When the QTcpSocket will be released by the `QTcpServer`? Only when the socket is explicitely disconnected? So in my case, will it never be destroyed? Should I manage the disconnection in all cases in the Android side?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP will not notify you of disconnections unless the remote peer explicitly sends disconnect request *(by using **close()** or **shutdown()** methods)* or you try to write to a disconnected socket (in which case you get a **broken pipe** signal)

The classical way to solve this problem is implementing a heartbeat messaging system where after a certain amount of heartbeat **inactivity** you close the socket concluding that the remote peer has died suddenly or there is a network problem.

Comment: This is what I fear. 

Is it a sort of polling system you advise me to implement? I mean: a regular timer which tests the state of the socket or the pipe? I hoped there would be a solution based on events or signals, but you confirm what I think.

Thanks.